# How to insert records to SQL with looked up values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel

**Scenario**

I need to update a SQL 2008 database daily via a spreadsheet (the only option available). The format is pretty basic, however there are potentially millions of records. Column1 and Column3 will have many predefined duplicate values, already pulled out into separate tables.

**Spreadsheet Sample**

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
Apple   10      Red
Apple   20      Red
Apple   15      Blue
Apple   21      Green
Orange  10      Orange
Orange  7       Orange
Orange  9       Red
Orange  70      Blue
Orange  10      Blue
```

**DB Setup**

My database is set up with three separate tables:

```
//Lookup_Column1
id type
1  Apple
2  Orange

//Lookup_Column3
id type
1  Red
2  Blue
3  Green
4  Orange

//Main - this is what should be inserted, after Column1
//and Column2 are matched to their respective ID's
key Column1 Column2 Column3
1   1       10      1
2   1       20      1
3   1       15      2
4   1       21      3
5   2       10      4
6   2       7       4
7   2       9       1
8   2       70      2
9   2       10      2
```

**Question**

How can I write the SQL to insert records that match the information from the lookup tables? How can I go from this:

```
INSERT INTO Main(Column1, Column2) VALUES ('Apple', 10, 'Red');
```

To this:

```
INSERT INTO Main(Column1, Column2) VALUES (1, 10, 1);
//pulled from lookup tables, where Apple = 1 and Red = 1
```

Comment: How do you plan to bring the spreadsheet data into sql-server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
    INSERT INTO Main(Column1, Column2, Column3) VALUES 
    (
    (SELECT id FROM Lookup_Column1 WHERE type = 'Apple'),
    10, 
    (SELECT id FROM Lookup_Column3 WHERE type = 'Red')
    );
```

There isn't any fault-tolerance, but it would work as long as you could parse your spreadsheet values into SELECT statements.

Answer (score 2):

The source of data that inserted into a table is defined as

```
   VALUES ( { DEFAULT | NULL | expression } [ ,...n ] ) [ ,...n ] 
          | derived_table 
          | execute_statement
          | <dml_table_source>
          | DEFAULT VALUES
```

So we can use a derived_table which is defined as

> *derived_table*
>
> Is any valid SELECT statement that returns rows of data
>   to be loaded into the table. The SELECT statement cannot contain a
>   common table expression (CTE).

```
 INSERT INTO 
   MAIN
 (Column1, Column2, column3)

 SELECT
   lc1.id,
   10,
   lc2.id
 FROM  
   Lookup_Column1 lc1,
   Lookup_Column2 lc2
  WHERE 
   lc1.type = 'Apple'
   and 
   lc2.type = 'Red'
```

For more information see [INSERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

If you could get your spreadsheet values into a staging table (or linked to the spreadsheet directly using a linked server or [OPENDATASOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx) ) you could change your INSERT clause to

```
  INSERT INTO 
   MAIN
  ( Column1, Column2, column3)
 SELECT
   lc1.id,
   s.column2,
   lc2.id

 FROM  
   OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
           'Data Source=C:\YourdataSource.xls;Extended Properties=EXCEL 5.0')...[Sheet1$] s
   INNER JOIN Lookup_Column1 lc1 
   ON s.column1 = lc1.type 
   INNER JOIN Lookup_Column2 lc2 
   ON s.column3 = lc2.type
```

This would allow you to remove the looping that you're currently thinking of doing.

Comment: How is this better than BryceAtNetwork23's answer, which seems simpler to me? (though both answers work)

Comment: If you're going to process the records one at a time they're the same.  If you use a staging table or OPENDATASOURCE to process them all at once then you have to use a derived_table

Comment: Understood, and thank you for your help. Unfortunately your method isn't available to me.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a SELECT INTO statement?  This allows you to select data from one table and insert it into another.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: SELECT INTO *creates* a table