# How can I perform insertions in django with lookups and condition dependent insertions?

Tags: python, sql, django, database, sqlite

I am trying to optimise database insertion of a large data set through django.
Here is a simple sample model that should be enough to demonstrate the issue I face.

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=8)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    first_registered = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Given the example model above. I can currently create rows in the following manner

```
school = app.models.School.objects.get_or_create(name='School 1', postcode='AB12 3CD')
student = app.models.Student.objects.create(name='Student 1', school=school[0])
```

This works well for the simple "getting started" case, but there are potential issues when expanding to a larger data set and more complex models with more relationships.

- The school entry requires a database round trip every time.
- Race conditions are possible.

I'll define a more real world problem.

- There is a master list of school and student data
- The students and school list is updated daily
- The data comes in no particular order
- Previous data may be present, but could also be removed
- Previous data may also be updated (outside scope of this question)

  - If it is removed then that indicates the student is no longer a student

In essence, each day a list is available with the current snapshot of all students and the school they attend.

Given the above, it's not hard to imagine perhaps 10,000 schools with 5,000,000 students, perhaps billions if looking on a global scale.

Some observations of the data include, that approx 95% of it is duplicated daily. So this data can be filtered quite quickly in a simple query.
Currently I have the following code that works well for filtering existing data, and also conditionally updating some of the fields too in a single SQL statement.

```
# See if the student already exists and is assigned to the school in the data set.
# If it does exist, get the database to update the last updated date and the first registration dates if needs be.
#
# Note: These updates are necessary as it is possible that data is imported in non-chronological order.
updated_fields = app.models.Student.objects.filter(
            name=data['student_name'],
            school__name=data['school_name'],
            school__postcode=data['school_postcode'],
        ).update(
            last_updated=Case(
                When(last_updated__lt=data['last_updated'], then=data['last_updated']),
                default=F('last_updated')
                ),
            first_registered=Case(
                When(first_registered_gt=data['first_registered'], then=data['first_registered']),
                default=F('first_registered')
                )
        )
```

The problem I face is when I get to insertion of new data I am getting stuck doing multiple database queries. There are far fewer schools than students and they are added at a slower rate.
Apart from the initial import, in all subsequent daily updates, 99.9% of the time the school data already exists in the database and the student just needs assigning.

Currently my importing literally works in the primitive way as follows and there are more FK lookups than shown, hence I am keen to reduce database round trips.

```
for entry in data:
    school = app.models.School.objects.get_or_create(name=entry['school_name'], postcode=entry['school_postcode'])
    student = app.models.Student.objects.create(name=data['student_name'], school=school[0])
```

What I would like to do is move that get_or_create into the create statement, and have it create it in the database if it doesn't exist at the point of insertion. I feel of the right way to do this is to let the database do all the work.

The idea is to pass all the Student and School information upon each insertion. The insert query should then try and lookup the school information and assign that entry to the FK for Student.
If that returns no result, the school should be created and then assigned the resulting FK.

I have found a similar question for SQL. [How to insert records to SQL with looked up values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287339/how-to-insert-records-to-sql-with-looked-up-values)
I think that is what I want, but with one key difference, my query should create the entry in the case of lookup failure

I was wondering if anyone has any idea how to do this in django, perhaps using functionality such as WHERE, CASE, etc..?
If the it is not possible through the ORM, some help via RAW SQL would be welcome.

FYI I am currently running django 1.10 and upgrading is not an issue. I am using sqlite backend (simply for ease rather than preference or features)

Many thanks,

Andy